# compare table column having type 'date' with variable having type 'month'

Tags: laravel, date, formatting, compare, where-clause

```
 public function collection()
{
   // dd($this->month);
    return User::whereMonth('date' , $this->month)->get();
}
```

I want to compare date type of table with month and year.
format of $this->month is "2021-03"
format of 'date' is "2021-03-25".
how I can compare both.
thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly Visit [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) 
WhereMonth param need only month and you are passing year and month.

Comment: $this->month is "2021-03" which is wrong format .
$this->month is "03" need to be like this.

Comment: I get ($this->month)  value from blade form , and In the form I put type as month and I get this kind of format.

Comment: You can use carbon Library 
try this


`use Carbon;`

 `public function collection()
{
   // dd($this->month);
    return User::whereMonth('date' , Carbon::parse($this->month)->month)->get();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use both `whereMonth` and `whereYear`.

```php
[$year, $month] = explode('-', $this->month);

return User::query()
    ->whereMonth('date', (int) $month)
    ->whereYear('date', (int) $year)
    ->get();
```